# How to view Print result RTL

Tags: javascript, css, printing, textarea, text-align

When i print text in textarea it shows LTR and my text is RTL so how can i fix this problem so the text will show up like is it left or right or center and i have another problem when i copy text area it aligns to right but sometime i have certain words in the center and they move to right in the text editor area

```html
<html ">
<head>
<title></title>
<!-- script print button -->
 <script type="text/javascript">
      function printTextArea() {
    
        childWindow = window.open('','childWindow','location=yes, menubar=yes, toolbar=yes');
        childWindow.document.open();
        childWindow.document.write('<html><head></head><body>');
        childWindow.document.write(document.getElementById('targetTextArea').value.replace(/\n/gi,'<br>'));
        childWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        childWindow.print();
        childWindow.document.close();
        childWindow.close();
      }
    </script>
<style type="text/css">
textarea {
direction: rtl; 
 background-color: white;
 font-size: 1em;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    <TEXTAREA name="thetext" rows="20" cols="80"id="targetTextArea" ></TEXTAREA>
   </p>
   <!-- print button -->
  <center> <input type="button" onclick="printTextArea()" value="طباعة"/></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give the child's body a direction attribute with the value rtl, so just change this line:

`childWindow.document.write('<html><head></head><body>');`

to this:

`childWindow.document.write('<html><head></head><body dir="rtl">');`

Comment: Still the same problem the arabic text is shown from left to right in the printed page result

Comment: I'm not sure if it'd be related but you need to replace `'<br>'` with `'<br/>'`

Comment: Silly me, the attribute is not `direction` it is `dir`, Updated the answer

Comment: but when i post english text it's on the right so how can i allow textarea to decide automaticlly if it's rtl or ltr and same with print result if a had a mixed text arabic and english it will print the text like it is without me choosing which direction

Comment: That needs a lot of work to do, what you need to do is to use regex to detect if it is all english or arabic and then based on that set the direction attribute. There are some good tutorials if you google a bit

Comment: how can i remove pop-up option so print page will show up in the same page instead of seperate new page by editing this script

Comment: You can create an iframe and then target that iframe.